# Can i read method inside arrow function after import

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I encounter a problem today and I want to know if there is a way to do it
  I want to read the method inside ModelTodo from another Component i hope its possible and i would like your help here

```
const ModelTodo =() => {
 let arrTodo = [];
 const addTodo = (todo) => {
    arrTodo.push(todo);
 };

 const updateTodo = (index, isDone) => {
    arrTodo[index].isDone = isDone;
 };

 const removeCompletedTodo = () => {
    arrTodo = this.arrTodo.filter(function (obj) {
        return !obj.isDone;
    });
  };

 const getCompletedTodo = () => {
    let arrCompletedTodo = this.arrTodo.filter( (obj) => obj.isDone === true);
    return arrCompletedTodo;
 };
 const getTodo = () => {
    return arrTodo;
 };
}

export default ModelTodo;
```

i do `import ModelTodo from '../model/modelTodo'` so there is a way

Comment: Just so it's a little clearer, do you realize that you've created and are exporting a function? If so, you want to access a variable inside the function? or returned by that function?

Comment: i want to get access to those action and try to do kinda of TODO list with MVC Architecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way

```
const ModelTodo = () => {

  // ...

  return {
    arrTodo,
    addTodo,
    updateTodo,
    removeCompletedTodo,
    getCompletedTodo,
    getTodo
  }
}

const model = ModelTodo()

export default model

// another file

import ModelTodo from '../model/modelTodo'

console.log(ModelTodo.arrTodo)
// []

ModelTodo.addTodo('balabala')

console.log(ModelTodo.arrTodo)
// ["balabala"]
```